# Form and Validation/CSS Issue

Tags: php, html, css, forms, checkbox

I have a form located here:

http://f14.co/auto-search/Test/

You'll see in the code that there is a form element about halfway down:

```
   </div>
        <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="final_form" action="send_mail.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="template" id="template" value="Buyers" />
            <div class="modal-body" >
                <div id="lead_info_1">
                    <div class="input select">
                        <div class=""></div>
                        <div class="span-4 step-2-dropdown append-bottom control-group">
                            <select class="span3 required" name="minPrice" id="minPrice">
```

About 1/4 of the way down there is a checkbox that I need to be inside the form to work with send_mail.php:

```
   <div class="sold"></div>
            <div class="form">

                 <h2>Search for your dream home<br />
       and save now!</h2>
                <legend>Which Areas are you interested in?</legend>
                <div class="areas row-fluid" style="text-align:left !important;">                       
                    <div class='span5' style='margin-left:0px !important;'>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="arrayValue[]" id="area[0]" value="test" style='margin-top:-5px !important;'> test</label>
                    </div>          
                    </div>
                <input type="button" onclick="jQuery('#myModal').modal('show')" value="CONTINUE" />
```

However, if I move the form element above the checkboxes, the error checking (the form turns red if values aren't filled out), goes away.

Anyone know how to preserve the error checking? I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. Not sure if this is a page code problem or a CSS issue.

Comment: How are you performing this error checking? Is it custom jQuery code or built in HTML5 or what?

Comment: It's built into the CSS through novalidate on the form element.

Comment: The link you provided is not working. Is it possible to send a like of uploaded code in http://bootply.com/

Comment: I don't have enough code to find what's wrong